# initialValues from Redux are not updating correctly

Tags: redux-form

I have a component that looks like this,

```
const errorAnalysisName = { name: undefined }

const ReduxForm = (props: ReduxFormProps) => {
  const { handleSubmit, children } = props
  return <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>{children}</Form>
}

const connectedForm = connect(state => {
  errorAnalysisName.name = 'insideRedux'
  return {
    errorAnalysisName: 'insideRedux'
  }
}, null)(ReduxForm)

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'CreateWizard',
  enableReinitialize: true,
  validate,
  destroyOnUnmount: false,
  initialValues: {
    baseScheduleChoice: 'load',
    newScheduleChoice: 'load',
    currentIndex: 0,
    name: errorAnalysisName.name
  }
})(ReduxForm)
```

The field `name` is not updating to `insideRedux`, anyone see what I'm missing here?

I want to pass an Initial Value from my State, but trying to do so won't update the initialValues object in reduxForm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want use use enableReinitialize you will wan't to set the initialValues prop when you render the redux form then if the prop ever changes the form will reinitialize.

I've modified your example slightly for brevity:

```
const CreateWizard = reduxForm({
  form: 'CreateWizard',
  enableReinitialize: true,
  destroyOnUnmount: false
})(({ handleSubmit, children }) => (
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>{children}</form>
));

const Container = connect(state => ({
  errorAnalysisName: state.errorAnalysisName
})(props => (
  <CreateWizard initialValues={{
    baseScheduleChoice: 'load',
    newScheduleChoice: 'load',
    currentIndex: 0,
    name: props.errorAnalysisName
  }} />
));

export default Container;
```